# Interactive (Rotable) PDF with 3D Plot

Tags: pdf, plot, 3d, interaction

Using (say) `Matlab`, it's very simple to create [3D surface plots](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/surf.html).

Is it possible to embed them into LaTeX such that the resulting PDF is interactive and one can rotate the figure and look at it from different angles?

Comment: well one could embed 3d files with media9 and view them with adobe reader, I have seen examples. But I don't know what the state is here after flash has been removed.

Comment: It is a standard PDF feature and does not depend on Flash, so it should still work. You can use e.g. Asymptote to generate the models. [There is also a Matlab plugin for generating U3D files (the format supported in PDF](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/37640-export-figure-to-3d-interactive-pdf) (But even though it is a standard PDF feature, it still isn't supported by any viewers beside Acrobat AFAIK)